# How to compile handlebarsjs from external json source?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, handlebars.js

See this link: http://jsfiddle.net/dASav/
it is working.
I use internal JSON data, code below.

```
  var data = { blogsTags: [
  {
    "tag": "GovernorBentley",
    "separation_path": "/blogs/byTag/GovernorBentley.html"
  },
  {
    "tag": "Huntsville",
    "separation_path": "/blogs/byTag/Huntsville.html"
  },
  {
    "tag": "Voting Rights",
    "separation_path": "/blogs/byTag/Voting Rights.html"
  }
    ]};
```

But i want the JSON data from external course. 
the JSON data link is: http://json.virtuecenter.com/json-data/blogs/tags
how can i do this? please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using [**jQuery.getJSON()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), inorder to fetch json from external url.

> **Description**: Load JSON-encoded data from the server using a GET HTTP
>   request.

There is nothing to do with Handlebars here.

A short example

```
$.getJSON( "http://json.virtuecenter.com/json-data/blogs/tags", function( json ) {
  //Handle it
 });
```

### Updates:

`jQuery.getJSON()` *is highly recommended method in jQuery for fetching json from external url.*

So how to work with it?

```
$.getJSON( "http://json.virtuecenter.com/json-data/blogs/tags?callback=?", function( json ) {
io (json);    //I have used method call for passing parameter
 });
```

Don't forget to add **`?callback=?`**, this will help to overcome CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)

Then you final code

```
function io (data) {
  var template = document.getElementById("movies-tmp").innerHTML;
var templateCompile = Handlebars.compile(template);
var result = templateCompile(data);
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", result);
}
```

Here is [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/dASav/1/)

Hope you understand.

Comment: thanks for your answer, can you please explain me in with more details? actually what will be the new code instead   var data = { blogsTags: [
  {
    "tag": "GovernorBentley",
    "separation_path": "/blogs/byTag/GovernorBentley.html"
  }
    ]};
      
var template = document.getElementById("movies-tmp").innerHTML;
var templateCompile = Handlebars.compile(template);
var result = templateCompile(data);
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", result);

Comment: @Rousnay I have added more explanation, hope this is helpful.  However sorry for the late response

Comment: @Rousnay Glad to help you my friend :)

Comment: Thanks for your fast help, can you help me for another one, please check the link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194008/handlebarsjs-templating-how-to-get-data-from-external-json-source