# (Handlebarsjs templating) How to get data from external JSON source?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp, handlebars.js

See this link: http://jsfiddle.net/Rousnay/FJzre/ it is working, the JSON data come trough `http://json.virtuecenter.com/json-data/blogs/tags?callback=?`

but it is not working when i want to get data from `http://sunday-theater-club.simpletix.eu/API/ThemeUIHandler.asmx/GetMenuItems?callback=?`

Can anyone help me with `jsfiddle` example. please.

Comment: Learn how to use the browser's developer tools. In the Network panel you can inspect the HTTP responses for those Ajax requests. Your second URL does not return a JSON with the same structure as the first URL.

Comment: i know the JSON source are not same, it is possible to get JSON data from http://sunday-theater-club.simpletix.eu/API/ThemeUIHandler.asmx/GetMenuItems?callback=? for `<script id="movies-tmp" type="text/x-template">
<a href="{{url}}">{{text}}</a> <br>
</script>`  like this one http://jsfiddle.net/Rousnay/FJzre/

Comment: Your template expects a "blogsTags" array but the JSON returned from the second URL does not provide such an array. What don't you understand? If you want a template to work with a specific JSON structure, you have to construct the template based on that structure. Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/FJzre/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned data is not valid to the template, when getting from "http://sunday-theater-club.simpletix.eu/API/ThemeUIHandler.asmx/GetMenuItems?callback=?" you end up with:

```
[
    {
        "text": "Home ",
        "url": "/Default.aspx" 
    },
    {
        "text": "Events ",
        "url": "/Event-List/"
    },
    {
        "text": "Test",
        "url": "/Pages/8276/Test/"
    }
]
```

and when getting from "http://json.virtuecenter.com/json-data/blogs/tags?callback=?" you have:

```
{
    "blogsTags": [
                     {
                         "tag":"GovernorBentley",
                         "count":1,
                         "separation_path":"\/blogs\/byTag\/GovernorBentley.html"
                     },
                     {
                         "tag":"Huntsville",
                         "count":1,
                         "separation_path":"\/blogs\/byTag\/Huntsville.html"
                     },
                     {
                         "tag":"Voting Responsibility",
                         "count":1,
                         "separation_path":"\/blogs\/byTag\/Voting Responsibility.html"
                     },
                     {
                         "tag":"Voting Rights",
                         "count":1,
                         "separation_path":"\/blogs\/byTag\/Voting Rights.html"
                     }
                 ],
                 "pagination": {
                     "limit":20,
                     "total":4,
                     "page":1,
                     "pageCount":1
                 }
}
```

your template expects a "blogsTags" property.

Comment: i know the JSON source are not same, it is possible to get JSON data from http://sunday-theater-club.simpletix.eu/API/ThemeUIHandler.asmx/GetMenuItems?callback=? for `<script id="movies-tmp" type="text/x-template">
<a href="{{url}}">{{text}}</a> <br>
</script>`  like this one http://jsfiddle.net/Rousnay/FJzre/